# Counting non-empty / non-zero row entries in each pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as follows:

```
Name | Gender | Age | Apple | Banana | Mango | Watermelon | Kiwi
----------------------------------------------------------------
Jack | Male   | 20  | 2     | 3      | 10    |            | 
Jen  | Female | 25  | 5     |        |       | 5          | 1
Jill | Female | 22  | 5     | 3      |       | 5          | 
John | Male   | 21  | 6     |        |       |            |
Joe  | Male   | 28  | 2     | 3      |       | 5          |
Jim  | Male   | 26  | 2     | 3      |       |            |
```

I want to find the count of non-empty cell in for all columns, grouped by say "Gender".

In other words, the desired output is to have:

```
Fruits     | Total | Male | Female |
------------------------------------
Apple      | 6     | 4    | 3      |
Banana     | 4     | 3    | 1      |
Mango      | 1     | 1    | 0      |
Watermelon | 3     | 2    | 1      |
Kiwi       | 1     | 0    | 1      |
-------------------------------------
Total      | 16     | 10   | 6
```

Please note:

```
>> print type(df.iloc[1,4])
<type 'str'>
```

So, there is empty string, which I cannot fill with `fillna()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) + [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) + [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) + [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) + [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df1 = df.drop(['Name', 'Age'], 1)
df = df1.replace({'':np.nan, 0:np.nan}).groupby('Gender').count().T
df.insert(0, 'Total', df.sum(1))
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
print (df)
Gender      Total  Female  Male
Apple           6       2     4
Banana          4       1     3
Mango           1       0     1
Watermelon      3       2     1
Kiwi            1       1     0
Total          15       6     9
```

Also if need change columns order add [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
df1 = df.drop(['Name', 'Age'], 1)
df = df1.replace({'':np.nan, 0:np.nan}).groupby('Gender').count().T
df['Total'] = df.sum(1)
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
df = df.reindex_axis(['Total','Male','Female'], 1)
print (df)
Gender      Total  Male  Female
Apple           6     4       2
Banana          4     3       1
Mango           1     1       0
Watermelon      3     1       2
Kiwi            1     0       1
Total          15     9       6
```

Comment: Damn it, I had all the required pieces in different places! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey @jazrael seems like ```df1.replace({'':np.nan}).groupby('Gender').count().T``` is not replacing the empty strings. I am getting wrong totals :(

Comment: how to replace empty string of any length

Comment: Try `df1.replace({\s+'':np.nan, regex=True})`. Untested, because only on phone.

Comment: I tried ```df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)``` and it seems to be working. Thanks!